# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined file upload Dropzone JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload a file, when an button is clicked. The issue is in the 2nd block of code

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

    autoProcessQueue: false,

    init: function () {
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
        myDropzone = this; 

        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            myDropzone.processQueue(); 
        });


        this.on("addedfile", function () {

        });

    }
};
```

Above is my create a new dropzone section, and down below is my logic.I get an error on my for loop. saying length is undefined.

```
$("#submit-all").click(function (e) {
    $('#myPleaseWait').modal('show')
    var fileUpload = $("#files").get(0);
    var files = this.file;
    var data = new FormData();
    var _url = $(this).data('appcontroller');
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length ; i++) { //Error is stopping here when upload button is pressed
        data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: _url,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (message) {
            $('#myPleaseWait').modal('hide');
            alert(message);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#myPleaseWait').modal('hide');
            alert("There was error uploading files!");
        }
    });
});
```

i've added a js fiddle with my html code https://jsfiddle.net/q47axhdf/2/

Any help would greatly appreciated

Comment: `var files = fileUpload.file;` should be `var files = fileUpload.files;`

Comment: hi rory, forgot to change that to this.files, which is why i'm getting my length undefined err message

Comment: So are you saying that it's now fixed?

Comment: yea I removed `.length` and it uploads fine.

Answer (score 0):

Like always found the answer after posting this. i removed `.length` from my file.length in the for loop and the upload works perfect.